# Getting cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) error after saving models in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, curl, request, laravel-5.4

I am having this error `cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)` after saving/creating multiple models to database.

I have this in my controller:

```
public function storeTruck(Request $request){
    //Save Company Detail
    $company = Company::Create($request->only(['company']));
    // Save Trucker Info
    $request->request->add(['password'=>bcrypt('trucker')]);
    $request->request->add(['company_id'=>$company->id]);
    $trucker = Trucker::create( $request->only([
        'first_name','last_name','company',
        'email','contact', 'password', 'company_id'
    ]));
    return view('admin.truck.list'); 
}
```

Those models are saved successfully in database but it will then proceed to a `cURL error 3` problem. What causes this error based on the codes? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: did you solved this, if yes, please reply with answer

Answer (score 13):

This error is due to the URL is not correct. Check the cURL error 3: [check this link](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake when instantiating the the Guzzle Client Object:

Rather than assigning my baseUrl to th 'base_uri' key as below,

```
$client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->baseUrl
    ]);
```

I assigned the $baseUrl to the 'base_url' key, which does not exist.

```
$client = new Client([
        'base_url' => $this->baseUrl
    ]);
```

Be careful when doing this. make sure you use 'base_uri' key instead of 'base_url'.

Comment: Damn I've I been looking in all the wrong places. I hate loosing time on a simple Typo. Thanks, that fixed my issue. Just rephrasing a bit though. You say "base_uri" key both times. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. [Download](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) download cacert.pem.
2. Save the file "cacert.pem" to your computer. For example **C:\PHP\cacert.pem**
3. Add the location of the "cacert.pem" file to your **php.ini** file.
   Search for `[curl.cainfo]` in your **php.ini** file and update the following line:
   `curl.cainfo = "C:\PHP\cacert.pem"`
4. Restart your web server.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error on Guzzle with WPEngine. I solved it by changing the protocol on the base_uri, from 'https' to 'http'